# Code re-use between 2 play projects

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, dependency-management, code-reuse

Suppose I have 2 play 2.3x projects A and B in the following structure

```
A
- app
  - a
    - controllers
    - models
    - integration
- conf
- build.sbt

B
- app
  - b
    - controllers
    - otherstuff
- conf
- build.sbt
```

I want to re-use the scala classes from a.integration and a.models in B. How can I do this? B is not logically a subproject of A, they are 2 separate services (not even in the same parent directory)  so the approach with SBT subprojects described in the docs does not seem right to me. I have tried exporting A to a jar with `SBT package` and adding that as a managed dependency (in the lib folder) of B but that runs into difficulties because the jar contains files which conflict with files in B (such as Global.scala). I would also worry that the dependencies of this jar might not be the same in A as in B and this would result in runtime failures.

Another approach would be to add the source of A as an additional source folder of B so it gets compiled with B but I don't know whether SBT supports this and how to make it work. This would not solve the issue of Global.scala and other unwanted files getting compiled along with the desired packages.

Back in the old days when I was a poor Java developer I could have solved this problem in about 5 minutes with ant and a fileset. Surely a modern tool like SBT can do this?

Perhaps I going about the whole thing wrong-headed and managed dependencies are what it is all about. But how to do this? Won't publishing the whole play application A to a maven/ivy repo cause the same dependency conflict problems in B or am I missing something (I'm afraid I am a complete Maven (and SBT) newbie so that is highly possible)

Specifically the code that I am trying to re-use is a bunch of case classes and a service client that wraps around the play WS client so perhaps creating a separate (non-play) library project that both projects could use with just the play WS dependency would also be an option but I have no idea whether this would work.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Extract the common files to an A-B-Api dependency and have both A and B depend on that jar.

Comment: Thanks Daenyth, I was beginning to think that was the right approach. What would be the correct SBT setup to for a plain library project to use the play framework WS classes without itself being a play project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daenyth said, introduce a separate subproject (or multiple), and depend on that from you project A and B

```
build.sbt <- declares all three sub-projects
webappA (depends on common)
webappB (depends on common)
common
```

In `common` you would have to add a dependency on the play library that contains WS (`com.typesafe.play % play-ws % [playversion]`) and if you want to run some kind of integration tests in `common` you would have to depend on and use the play test fixtures since WS requires a running play app to work.

Another option, if you do not usually work with A and B at the same time, or it just does not fit your mental model of the projects to make them into subprojects of one project, then you might be better off just having three separate projects, publishing versions your `common` project to a maven or ivy-repository and then depending on those release just like you do with other libraries.